# Can't update variable in a do while loop

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go first or second?");
string firstSecond = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
if (firstSecond == "FIRST")
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
else if (firstSecond == "SECOND")
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
else
{
    string input = "x";
    bool first = input == "FIRST";
    bool second = input == "SECOND";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please say first or second:");
        input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
    while (!(first | second));
}
```

The do while loop keeps on going even if I type first or second, I tried changing how I state the boolean but nothing seems to work. I am new so I am might some silly mistakes. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put `first` and `second` condition into `do while` loop.

```
string input;
bool first;
bool second;
do {
  Console.WriteLine("Please say first or second:");
  input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

  first = input == "FIRST";
  second = input == "SECOND";
}
while (!(first || second));
```

Comment: The difference between `first | second` and `first || second` when both `first` and `second` are boolean is that both operands are evaluated in the `|` case, but in the second (`||`) case, you get short-circuiting behavior (if `first` is true, `second` is not evaluated). The code-gen is simpler in the `|` case and the execution speed is likely (infinitesimally) better (without the short-circuiting branch). Idiomatically, most C# programmers will feel more comfortable with the short-circuiting form (BTW, in VB, `|` is the familiar `Or`, while `||` is the more unusual `Or Else`)